# can't connect to the gpg-agent: IPC connect call failed in windows 10 vscode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, certificate, gnupg

I want to singing my commit in git but vscode cli return this error !

```
git commit -S -m 'Message Commit'
```

> gpg: can't connect to the gpg-agent: IPC connect call failed
>
> gpg:keydb_search failed: No agent running
>
> gpg: skipped "MYName myEmail@gmail.com": No agent running
>
> gpg: signing failed: No agent running error:
>
> gpg: failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object
>
> error: gpg failed to sign the data
>
> fatal: failed to write commit object

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. In windows 10 and 11 we need add `gpg` program address to **git config** to `Keys` work correctly

```
git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
```

This work for me